# Specific Rule for elements that exceeds the parent's Width

Tags: javascript, css, dom

When a child Element have a higher width than his parent, it exceeds the parent's Width.
I want To Instead it exceeds the parent's Width, it Make have this `right` setted to '0' making it stick to the Right of the parent's Div, Is it possible?

See that example: http://jsfiddle.net/rTg3x/3/
The *inner1* div exceeds the *main* div limits, while the *inner2* div doesnt, I want to the inner1 div get sticked to the right side, without knowing the amount of `left` CSS that it have.

Is that possible?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try some nasty jQuery. Here's what I came up with. It works, but there are probably cleaner ways of doing it.

```
if(($('#inner1').offset().left + $('#inner1').width()) > $('#main').width()){
    $('#inner1').css({'right':'0', 'left': 'auto'});
}
```

Basically that says that if the width of your div plus its offset from the left is greater than the width of the parent, to right-align it.

More generic for ya.

```
$('#main').find('div').each(function() {
    if($(this).offset().left + $(this).width() > $('#main').width()) 
        $(this).css({'right':'0', 'left': 'auto'});

});
```

​

Comment: Wow, that one was nice, I tried with simple Javascript, but i cant some them with the final PX, now with JS you get it just in Numbers! Learned two things on that answer, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry for making another question, but is that possible to make it with classes or Tags instead of Id? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Updated with a more generic version.

Comment: Now it is Awesome, just legendary, thanks a lot! So it basically search for divs inside the Main div with this: .find('div') , right? Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**: In this case, it is not possible.

Your inner dividers in this case are positioned absolutely so there is no relationship with the parent divider. It extends out because you have stated `left` and `top` values that cause this. This would not be the case with relatively positioned child dividers.

Comment: Hmm, But if inst Abosulte, if it is Relative, instead of left using margin-left, would it be possible? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if I understood your question.

Is this what you are looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/rTg3x/5/??

Comment: No, isnt that, If exceeds the parent's Width it should get sticked to the right side, not invisible, understand? Anyway, Thanks a lot!